# Vim: Avoiding recursive <Esc> shortcut

Tags: recursion, vim

Like most `vim` users, I have a convenience `<Esc>` shortcut:

```
:nnoremap ;j <Esc>
```

However now I have the following scenario:
I have a function, which inserts an `if statement` into my document:

```
autocmd FileType c nnoremap <localleader>si :call RemapTabC()<CR>iif ()<CR>{<CR>}<Esc>--f)i
```

`RemapTabC()` looks like this:

```
function RemapTabC()
    inoremap <buffer> <Tab> <Esc>:call UnmapTab()<CR>jo
    inoremap <buffer> <Esc> <Esc>:call UnmapTab()
endfunction
```

And I think the bug should be obvious.
I use `<localleader>si`, and the template appears. My cursor is in the conditional clause. Now I enter what I want to, and now I have two choices:

1. I click Tab. Works fine, it puts my cursor into the if-statement body.
2. I click Esc. Works also fine, BUT now if I use my remap `;j`, because it will directly map to `<Esc>`, instead of to my remapped `<Esc>`.

I could just make my `nnoremap ;j <Esc>` recursively, but I'm really afraid of it wreaking havoc. Do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try instead to listen for `InsertLeave` event instead of playing with  `<esc>`.

You can also have `<tab>` always active and ready to jump to the next placeholder -- and yes indeed, in the end, you'll define what several "big" plugins have already defined.

Comment: I know, but it's more of a learning experience. I feel the more comfortable I'm using `vimscript`, the more comfortable I'm using `vim`